# CloudFlare Shared SSL certificate forbids CraftCMS control panel sign in

Tags: request, https, ssl, cloudflare

I am running a site using CraftCMS and have a shared CloudFlare SSL certificate in place. Based on my understanding, the content source (i.e. my website) is not safe, while the content delivered to the user by CloudFlare is secure. While accessing the website works perfectly fine, logging in to the Control Panel is a major issue.

Now I am assuming that I will need an SSL certificate available on my server to secure the content source and thereby be able to log into the control panel using the `https` domain as opposed to the IP address or the `http` alternative.

Am I getting this correct or is there some way to log into the control panel using a shared CloudFlare SSL certificate?

Here is the console message I am referring to:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.mysite.com/admin/login' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.mysite.com/index.php/admin/actions/users/login'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Comment: Are you defining your Craft Site URL setting with http or https?

Answer (score 1):

I'd give [Patrol](https://github.com/selvinortiz/craft.patrol) plugin a try, just activate secure connections.